# d3d9 proxy dll - simulate mouse click

Tags: c++, proxy, directx, mouseclick-event

I am using a d3d9 proxy dll.

Within this proxy dll i try to send a mouseclick to the application which has loaded this dll:

```
    HWND mywin = FindWindow(NULL, "My Window Name");
    PostMessage ( mywin, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));
    Sleep(5);
    PostMessage ( mywin, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));
```

But the application is ignoring it.

Where when i use

```
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "", "left", 1, 420, 135)
```

from an external autoit program it regocnizes it and it works fine.

Since autoit is not open source i have no idea which windows api call they use for it.

Comment: DirectX-Apps usually use DirectInput for mouse and keyboard handling, which ignores the windows message loop. So the reason why your code fails is quite clear, but I don't know how autoIt works.

Comment: @PMF: Using DirectInput for mouse and keyboard is not recommended, even by MS, as it doesn't add anything useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood: Interesting, newer read that before. But I guess it's still a good idea to use DirectInput if you want to handle both Joystick and Mouse/Keyboard with similar code. I agree that it does not add value if you only need to handle Mouse or Keyboard in your Application.

Comment: @AndreasHinderberger: Seems you're coding an aimbot.

Comment: the strange thing is... it works when the target window is not active...